# jQuery, on hover, only show this one and not all of it's siblings

Tags: jquery

On page load, I'm hiding the class ".work-info".
When the mouse is over ".work-item" I'm trying to only show that one instance of ".work-info" instead of it showing all of it's siblings as well.

I've tried

```
 jQuery(".work-item").mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).$btn.show();
    }); 
  jQuery(".work-item").mouseleave(function(){
        jQuery(this).$btn.hide();
    });
```

but this is wrong.

This is what I currently have:

```
var $btn = jQuery('.work-info').hide();


jQuery(".work-item").mouseenter(function () {
    $btn.show();
});

jQuery(".work-item").mouseleave(function () {
    $btn.hide();
});
```

Comment: Your run+on sentence (no periods where needed) make your scenario a little confusing. Could you update it for clarity?

Comment: Sorry, hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Much better! How do you know which `work-info` element you want if the mouse is over `work-item`?

Comment: Please show your html so we can see what the issue is. Are there lots of ".work-info"? which one instance of ".work-info" ? are they next to each other? see the confusion?

Comment: I can't really show my html because I'm editing this through the wordpress dashboard. I'm using the theme Salient and it has a raw jquery element that I've put on the page. The ".work-item" will consist of around 5 elements with that class. the page is a portfolio. When the user's mouse enters one of these ".work-item" divs, I would like the hover to show this class of ".work-info". I'm currently hiding all ".work-info"s on the page when loaded so that the information in that div is not displayed, but only will show when there is a hover event.

Comment: we need the html that the JavaScript is being applied to or else cannot help...get the rendered source from your page please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want

```
// hide all 
jQuery('.work-info').hide();


jQuery(".work-item").mouseenter(function () {
    // use jquery find on the current selector
    jQuery(this).find(".work-info").show();
});

jQuery(".work-item").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery(this).find(".work-info").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('.work-info').hide(); 
$('.work-item').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.work-info').show();
});

$('.work-item').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.work-info').hide();
});
```